# Type refinement between function and non-function type

Tags: typescript

I have a state updater function that receives a previous state and enables you to set the new state via entire object or function updater. Eg.

```
const prevState = { x: 3 };
// Option A
const nextState = updateState(prevState, { x: 4 }); 
// Option B
const nextState = updateState(prevState, prevState => ({ x: prevState.x + 1 }));
```

I could type this in Flow, but can no longer make it work in TypeScript. Here is the function:

```
function updateState<State>(
  prevState: State,
  updater: State | ((prevState: State) => State),
): State {
  return typeof updater === 'function' ? updater(prevState) : updater;
}
```

And this is the error:

> Cannot invoke an expression whosetype lacks a call signature. Type '((prevState: State) => State) | (State & Function)' has no compatible call signatures.

Where does `(State & Function)` come from?

My understanding is that `State` itself can also be a function, since `State` is untyped. But maybe I can restrict `State` to a non-function type...

Is there any way to make this work in TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the fact that `State` is a generic type parameter, so there is no reason `State` could not be a function. So when you use the type-guard the result of the narrowing can't exclude `State` from the type. All the type-guard can say is that the new type will also be a function, this means the original type in an intersection with`Function`, which following the rules of how these types can be expanded we get : `(State | ((prevState: State) => State)) & Function = (State & Function) | (((prevState: State) => State) & Function ) = (State & Function) | (((prevState: State) => State))`

One thing we can do is make sure that `State` is not compatible with Function (there is no explicit way to say a generic type can't be a specific type, we can only say what a type can be).

```
function updateState<State extends { call?: never } & Record<string, any>>( // if State has a call member it must be never
  prevState: State,
  updater: State | ((o: State) => State),
): State {
  return typeof updater === "function" ? updater(prevState) : updater;
}
```

One drawback of the solution is that the constraint basically forces `State` to be an object. If you want `State` to be a primitive as well you will need to add primitives back in with a union:

```
function foo<S extends string | number | boolean | null | undefined | { call?: never }>(initial: S | (() => S)): S {
    return typeof initial === 'function' ? initial() : initial;
}

foo('test');
```

Comment: `extends { call?: never }` is brilliant. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting idea, but it does not appear to work? Trying to use the function fails. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20foo%3CS%20extends%20%7B%20call%3F%3A%20never%20%7D%3E(initial%3A%20S%20%7C%20(()%20%3D%3E%20S))%3A%20S%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20typeof%20initial%20%3D%3D%3D%20'function'%20%3F%20initial()%20%3A%20initial%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afoo('test')%3B%0D%0A

Comment: @JonRimmer edited the answer, there is an issue around primitives but it can work for those as well

Comment: Primitive values aside, it seems that the `{ call?: never }` doesn't work for objects -- except for empty objects. Any property in the object will yield `Argument of type '{ x: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ call?: undefined; }'`. I found `{ call?: never, [key: string]: any; }` a working alternative to extend. Would you consider it a viable solution?

Comment: @treznik hm I am pretty sure it worked when I wrote it. Modified the code to make it work with 3.3.  10x for pointing it out, sometimes errors creep in either by mistake or due to TS changes :)

Comment: This will also work `function updateState<State extends { call?: never } & object>`